# how do I know a rdlc report is printed

Tags: c#, reportviewer

I need to have a restriction for report printing. When a user prints some specific report He wont be able to print it again. İnorder to print he need to get permission from the manager.

The problem here is that I  am not able to know whether print function processed or not. Is there a way like adding event handler to Rdlc reportviewer that works after document is printed.

Comment: How would you handle the case where the report is printed, but someone else takes it off the printer? This sounds like an unreasonable requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the [`ShowPrintButton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.reportviewer.showprintbutton.aspx) property to false to prevent the print button from appearing as part of the control. You can then create your own "print" button, and invoke the print dialog from client code. See "[ReportViewer class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd756405.aspx)".

Of course, your client-side print function would also have to perform the "print only once" functionality.